# Angular 5: Lazy-loading of component without routing

Tags: angular, angular5, lazy-loading

In my web application I have a "Terms and Conditions" popup that opens by link click in the footer (so it's a core component).
Popup comprises of several tabs, each of them is a pretty big template file.

I wonder if it's possible to move tab templates to separate chunk and organize their lazy-loading? I'm not sure if default Angular lazy-loading is acceptable for me because I don't want to have separate route for the popup.

Comment: There are no *built in* features to lazy load just components, but you can create a solution to do it. The problem is that it's way more work than just using the already supported lazy modules for routes. Here's a post on the topic: https://blog.angularindepth.com/dynamically-loading-components-with-angular-cli-92a3c69bcd28

Comment: I found this great guide, https://www.dzurico.com/angular-lazy-load-modules-with-cli/

Comment: This lybrary lazy load component without routing https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lazy-load-component

Answer (score 5):

You can wait for the user to click on the link and as soon as Click Event occurs, load the required component in the view.
Things to keep in mind:

1. You need to have a placeholder defined for the component in the view.
2. The terms and conditions component needs to be defined as **Entry level component** for it's Module or the module where it is used.

   ```
    entryComponents: [
       ChildComponent
     ],
   ```
3. Make sure to refer to the placeholder in your component and attach the terms and condition component dynamically.

   ```
     <div>
         <ng-template #viewContainerRef></ng-template>
      </div>
   ```

and

```
@ViewChild('viewContainerRef', { read: ViewContainerRef }) VCR: ViewContainerRef;
```

and create the component dynamically:

```
createComponent() {

    let componentFactory = this.CFR.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
    let componentRef: ComponentRef<ChildComponent> = this.VCR.createComponent(componentFactory);
    let currentComponent = componentRef.instance;

    currentComponent.selfRef = currentComponent;
  // to track the added component, you can reuse this index to remove it later
    currentComponent.index = ++this.index; 

    // providing parent Component reference to get access to parent class methods
    currentComponent.compInteraction = this;

}
```

there is an example for you here: https://add-or-remove-dynamic-component-parent-child.stackblitz.io