# Angular 6 - How to use a dynamically created DIV as a ViewContainerRef

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I am playing around with Renderer2 and ViewContainerRef in Angular 6.
I wanted to dynamically render a new component to a **div** that was rendered by Renderer2.

So basically, this is how i want it to happen.

```
const el = this.renderer.createElement('div');
this.viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef = el;
const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(element.elementComponentType);
const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
```

and here is how the rendered HTML should look like

```
<div> <--- This will be the viewContainerRef
    <app-component></app-component> <--- this is the dynamic Component that I want to render
</div>
```

— Update —

Already found the answer to my prayers, thanks to Max.

Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44853707

It turns out that didn’t need a new view viewContainerRef to display a factory.

Mods, can close this now or reference this to the link i mentioned above.

Comment: But you do need to append this dynamically created Div to the view/body before you add dynamic components to it.

Comment: @nicraft Yeah i already did that, but how do i use that dynamically creted div? One that i could think of was assign a anchor name but that’s not possible for a dynamic element afaik

Comment: I don't think it's possible. ViewContainers are defined during compilation. Why do you need to dynamically create view container?

Comment: @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard because i am trying to follow a layout that I defined for certain components. Are there any work arounds that I can do to make this work? I am really open to suggestions.

Comment: @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard  i found the answer and it was your answer from another question before.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44853707

Comment: I would prefer the approach of using ` @ViewChild('element', {read: ViewContainerRef}) private anchor: ViewContainerRef;` in stead of modifying DOM outside the angular. as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53191913/9386929