# How to create a component in angular (programmatically) with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables

I'm trying to create a `mat-spinner` next to a custom button of a datatable with jquery with no luck so far:

The button is configured as below:

```
{
    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Export',
    className: 'btn btn-success btn-sm',
    init: function(api, node) {
       //...
    },
    action: function() {/*...*/}
 }
```

After configuring the table I create an `ng-container` in the following way:

```
this.table
  .buttons()
  .container()
  .append($('<ng-container #export/>'));
```

I can see the tag is added to the DOM but it's like it doesn't exist for angular 'cause adding `@ViewChild('export', {read: ViewContainerRef}) export` to my compononent's class always results in `undefined`. This way I would be able to create dynamically the `MatSpinner` and add it to the `export` container.

I also tried to create the spinner the same way as the `ng-container` but the same result. Do you have any idea how I would get this done?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't mix angular with jQuery. Since you are manipulating DOM directly without using angular API , the above code is not working. Angular has a different mechanism to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that I shouldn't mix angular and jquery but I don't know how to add the component where I want to add it the angular way with the code I have. I thought adding the ng-container via jquery and then continue to add the spinner the angular way.

Comment: @dcg, check this for the dynamic component creation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53191913/9386929

Comment: @nircraft Thanks for your reply. I already know how to do that. The thing is that by the time the buttons are created (by the datatable) is that I know where the component should be. My problem is that I'm not able to tell angular to "re-query" the `ViewContainerRef` some how and always give me `undefined`, so I'm not able to insert the `MatSpinner` the way you pointed me out.

Comment: This problem isn’t specific to mixing jQuery with Angular. It’s simply equivalent to opening developer tools and adding an HTML tag with ng-container and expecting angular to somehow have compiled it.

Comment: @javascript-sucks The tag goes inside what the datatable generates at runtime, so I'm not able to do it before, hence can't explicitly code the `ng-container` tag but after that happens.