# Lazy loading for a child component

Tags: angular, components, lazy-loading

I have a component that in the html call another component, I would implement lazy loading for this child component but didn't get how to do that.
That's my parent component html:

```
  <div>
    <child-component *ngIf="dataReady" [sortField]="sortField" [sortDir]="sortDir"></child-component>
  </div>
```

and I have my appmodule where I import the component:

```
import { Childcomponent } from './map-management/child-component.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Childcomponent
    ]
```

How can make the parent component to load lazy child-component?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules have you read thru this? Please don't feel discouraged if it doesn't make any sense at first glance, the module system in Angular can take some time to get comfortable with.

Comment: @Eyeslandic Thanks for the answer, but I don't have any route for my children component as the guide explain and I don't wanna change my route

Comment: Well, you're going to need one to use lazy loading, another solution would be dynamic components

Comment: I'm still struggling with this problem, what do you mean with dynamic components?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50648142/angular-5-lazy-loading-of-component-without-routing 

I think this is same as your problem, the answer given is for angular 5, it might still work